# Laptop temperature is inconsistent between sensors

Tags: laptop

The laptop equipped with i7-1165g7 CPU (tJunction is 100C)
running sensors command these are the max temp values:
package-id-0 is 96C
cores are 91-96C
CPU is not above 89C

Comment: I don't really see the problem in inconsistency – the sensors report different temperatures because they are in different positions, after all? Your CPU is reaching 89°C _at all_ is the actual problem, however...

Comment: I'm more worried about the 91-96C of the cores and package ID 96... what intel means by temp on die, is it the CPU the cores or package ID..

Comment: Consider that water *boils* at 100°C, and low-temp solders (e.g., In-based) not much above that. You can use that CPU to cook dinner.